# How to replace one or more \ in string with just \?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

Consider the string,

```
this\is\\a\new\\string
```

The output should be:

```
this\is\a\new\string
```

So basically one or more `\` character should be replaced with just one `\`.
I tried the following:

```
str = str.replace("[\\]+","\")
```

but it was no use. The reason I used two `\` in `[\\]+` was because internally `\` is stored as `\\`.  I know this might be a basic regex question, but I am able to replace one or more normal alphabets but not `\` character. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`str.replace("[\\]+", "\")` has few problems,

- `replace` doesn't use regex (`replaceAll` does) so `"[\\]"` will represent `[\]` literal, not `\` nor `\\` (depending on what you think it would represent)
- even if it did accept regex `"[\\]"` would not be correct regex because `\\]` would escape `]` so you would end up with unclosed character class `[..`
- it will not compile (your replacement String is not closed)

It will not compile because `\` is start of escape sequence `\X` where `X` needs to be either

- changed from being String special character to simple literal, like in your case `\"` will escape `"` to be literal (so you could print it for instance) instead of being start/end of String,
- changed from being normal character to be special one like in case of line separators `\n` `\r` or tabulations `\t`.

Now we know that `\` is special and is used to escape other character. So what do you think we need to do to make `\` represent literal (when we want to print `\`). If you guessed that it needs to be escaped with another `\` then you are right. To create `\` literal we need to write it in String as `"\\"`.

Since you know how to create String containing `\` literal (escaped `\`) you can start thinking about how to create your replacements.

Regex which represents one or more `\` can look like

`\\+`

But that is its native form, and we need to create it using String. I used `\\` here because in regex `\` is also special character (for instance `\d` represents *digits* , not `\` literal followed by `d`) so it also needs to be escaped first to represent `\` literal. Just like in String we can escape it with another `\`.

So String representing this regex will need to be written as

`"\\\\+"` (we escaped `\` twice, once in regex `\\+` and once in string)

You can use it as first argument of `replaceAll` (because `replace` as mentioned earlier doesn't accept regex).

Now last problem you will face is second argument of `replaceAll` method. If you write

`replaceAll("\\\\+", "\\")`

and it will find match for regex you will see exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing
```

It is because in `replacement` part (second argument in `replaceAll` method) we can also use special formula `$x` which represents *current match from group with index `x`*. So to be able to escape `$` into literal we need some escape mechanism, and again `\` was used here for that purpose. **So `\` is also special in replacement part** of our method.
So again to create `\` literal we need to escape it with another `\`, and string literal representing expression `\\` is `"\\\\"`.

But lets get back to earlier exception: message "character to be escaped is missing" refers to `X` part of `\X` formula (X is character we want to be escaped). Problem is that earlier your replacement `"\\"` represented only `\` part, so this method expected either `$` to create `\$`, or `\\` to create `\` literal. So valid replacements would be `"\\$` or `"\\\\"`.

---

To make things work you need to write your replacing method as

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\+", "\\\\")
```

Comment: Now thats some great explanation!! One thing I didn't know was: replace doesn't take regex and the IllegalArgumentException thing is very useful! I sometimes tend to forget this! Thanks a ton !

Comment: I can recommend `Matcher.quoteReplacement()` for escaping the replacement-string. Like `str = str.replaceAll("\\\\+", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\"))`

Comment: @MichaF. Yes, that could be useful if we want to avoid manual escaping, or when we can't do it because replacement is provided dynamically at runtime (like from console or file).

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
str = str.replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

Remember that `String#replace` doesn't take a regex.

Comment: Well thats strange! I din't know String#replace doesn't accept regex! I used Pattern, Matcher and it works now! Thanks.`Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[\\\\]+").matcher(str);if(m.find())path=m.replaceAll("\\\\");}'

Comment: This won't work for the following input: `String s = "this\\is\\\\a\\new\\\\\\string";`, or anything with more than two backslashes in a row.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\+", "\\\\");
```

Answer (score 1):

When writing regular expressions, you typically need to double-escape backslashes. So you would do this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\+", "\\\\");
```

Comment: `replace` doesn't tread first argument as regex. You probably wanted `replaceAll` but in this case you will also need to escape ``\\`` twice in second argument

Comment: @Pshemo I corrected `replace` to `replaceAll` moments before your comment, but indeed you're right about the replacement string. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `Matcher.quoteReplacement()` and `String.replaceAll()` here.

Like this:

```
String s;
[...]
s = s.replaceAll("\\\\+", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\"));
```